# Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Convert the contract to "address" type to access the member

Tags: solidity, remix

I have looked at the other posts with similar warning but I do not see how they apply to my context.

This is the exact line that is causing the error:

`players[index].transfer(this.balance);`

which is inside of this function:

```
function pickWinner() public {
  require(msg.sender == manager);
  uint index = random() % players.length;
  players[index].transfer(this.balance);
  players = new address[](0);
}
```

I am not sure if I should understand this literally, because I have not seen any documentation of what to use in lieu of `balance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is typecast as a contract. Earlier compilers did the conversion to type `address` implicitly the way you wrote it. Newer compilers want it done explicitly.

`players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);`

That's it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the contract instance itself, which means it is of type `contract`.

As of solidity 0.4.21, you need to cast `this` to type `address` to access the member functions of that type, such as `balance`.

Try:

```
  players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make two changes.
first,

```
address payable[] public players;
```

sencond,

```
players

[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
```